# BIOS Interrupt 13 read sector not working

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-16, bootloader

I have gotten into assembly operating system development and I am setting up a two-stage bootloader at the moment. I have set up the first stage, but when I  reset the disk and read the second sector, i get a bunch of giberish on screen. When I try to call the code that should have been loaded at `0x1000`, nothing happens (as far as I am aware). I have tried to find solutions, but none of them that I have found seem to work, and I am running out of luck. Here is my full code:

```
    BITS 16

start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096
    
    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax
    
    call reset
    call read_sector
    
    jmp sector
    
    text_string db "hello, world!", 0
    sector equ 1000h

reset:
    mov ah, 00h
    mov dl, 00h
    int 13h

read_sector:
    ; 1000h (used to be 07E0h, but changed as I realized that I probably needed to accomodate more space for the bootloader)
    mov ax, sector
    mov es, ax
    mov ah, 02h
    mov al, 01h
    mov ch, 00h
    mov cl, 02h
    mov dh, 00h
    mov dl, 00h
    int 13h
    jc reset

printf:
    mov ah, 0Eh
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je done
    int 10h
    jmp printf

jump_print:
    call printf
    ret

done:
    ret
    
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
; sector 2

message db 'now there is a different message!', 0
mov si, message
call printf

jmp $

times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

Any assistance would be great. For reference, I am on windows and I am compiling using nasm. I am testing through VirtualBox (which probably isn't the best tool, I know, but it works as I have seen so far).

Comment: Did you single-step it in a debugger to see what happens?  I don't see an `org 0x1000`, or any way for the assembler to calculate the right relative offset for `call printf` if these aren't loaded contiguously.

Comment: Your `read_sector` doesn't appear to `ret` when it succeeds.  You seem to have the segment and offset of your `sector` load address muddled: you load the offset into `es`, where the segment is expected, and the offset is expected in `bx` which you never load at all.  And even if that sector did load properly, it looks like the first thing in it is `message`, so you'd execute data when you jump to it.

Comment: Note that bochs has a much more useful debugger for real-mode code.  And a good debugger is essential here - if you can't see what's going on, you're never going to get it fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some problems:

a) The BIOS "read disk sector/s" function requires a segment (in `ES`) and an offset (in `BX`). You aren't providing an offset (not setting `BX` to anything) so there's no sane way to guess where the BIOS might load the sector (it could be anywhere within the 64 KiB segment requested by `ES`).

b) Regardless of how `sector` is created, it can't be a segment (for the `mov ax, sector`, `mov es, ax`) and also be an "offset in the current code segment" (for `jmp sector`), so one of them must be wrong. For "sector = 0x1000" it looks like it was supposed to be an "offset in current code segment" (and that the code to read the sector should set ES to 0x07C0 to match the assumed current code segment and do `mov bx,sector` to treat `sector` as an offset in the requested segment).

c) I'd strongly recommend setting segments to zero wherever possible. This helps to avoid confusion and mistakes (especially for beginners) and makes it much easier to switch to/from protected mode (or long mode) later. To do this you would need to use `org 0x7C00` (rather than "implied org 0 because it wasn't explicitly set") in addition to changing segment register loads (e.g. `mov ax, 07C0h`, `mov es,ax` would become `mov ax, 0`, `mov es,ax`). This would include the stack (where I'd recommend using "SS:SP = 0:0x7C00"). Don't forget that the stack segment limit often doesn't actually limit anything - e.g. a `push` or `call` when the stack is "full" just causes SP to overflow and wrap around from 0x0000 to 0xFFFE.

d) Resetting the disk system shouldn't be necessary before trying to read sector/s the first time (as you know the BIOS successfully read your boot loader and the disk system is working fine). It should only be used as an attempt to recover from disk errors. Note that (for floppy disks) resetting the disk system typically means recalibrating the drive which involves sending the heads back to "track 0".

e) When there's errors reading from disk, sometimes they're temporary (e.g. due to floppy drive motor speed variations) and sometimes they aren't (e.g. "bad parameters", "floppy disk ejected", etc). Retrying several times (and resetting the disk system occasionally between attempts) is recommended for working around temporary problems (especially for floppy disks). Slamming the disk heads back and forth forever (with "reset/recalibrate, seek/read, reset/recalibrate, seek/read, ...) is an extremely bad way to deal with persistent problems. You need a counter to track how many times you've retried so that you can stop after a limited amount of attempts and display an error message. Don't forget that BIOS returns an error code, and using that error code to determine which error message to display can help you find bugs and also help normal users figure out what to do when there's a problem (e.g. if it's faulty hardware/dodgy floppy disk or a software bug).

f) You have control flow problems. Specifically, you `call reset` but that code has no `ret` and falls through into the `read_sector` code; so `call reset` won't return unless the BIOS successfully reads the sector, and there's no point doing the `call read_sector` after the sector was already successfully read.

g) If the `read_sector` code succeeds it will fall through to the code to print a string. Your code to print a string (the `printf` routine) will get characters from the memory at the address contained in `DS:SI`, but `SI` is never set to anything in the 1st sector (before its executed) so it will probably only ever print a random/undefined mess (most likely case is that the byte at the unknown address happens to be zero and nothing is printed). Also; after reading a byte with `lodsb` `SI` will either be incremented or decremented depending on how the "direction flag" was set. Your code doesn't set the direction flag to anything (e.g. no `cld` instruction anywhere); which means that there's an extremely small chance that your code might print a random string backwards ("!dlroW olleH"). I don't know if you intended to have a `ret` after the code to read a sector, or if you intended to set `DS:SI` to the address of a "2nd sector loaded!" string (I assume the former because there's no string in the 1st sector).

h) The contents of the second sector starts with a string ("`now there is a different message!`"). If there were no other bugs, `call sector` (in 1st sector) would have caused this string to be executed and not valid code (likely causing a spectacular crash of some sort). You want to either move the string somewhere else (after the code in the second sector) or jump to the code directly (e.g. a `jmp sector2_code` in the 1st sector and a `sector2_code:` label before the `mov si, message` instruction).

i) The BIOS function you're using to read sectors mostly doesn't work for hard disks (modern hard disks are simply too big - there's an "extended disk read" function you'd want to use instead). For floppy disks you can't use the "extended disk read" function (and have to use the BIOS function that you are using). For other cases (booting from USB flash, booting from a CD configured to emulate something) you will need either a "BIOS Parameter Block" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block ) for floppy and floppy emulation, or a partition table (for hard disk or hard disk emulation). For actual real floppy disks, the "BIOS Parameter Block" is technically optional (originally part of the FAT file system and nothing to do with the BIOS at all), but it's common for other operating systems (Windows) to complain about the disk not being valid/formatted if there is none (which really confuses normal users).

j) Windows is malware that can/will corrupt 4 bytes in the first sector of a disk (in the middle of your boot sector's code), even though Windows has no right to tamper with competing operating system's disks or boot loaders. Specifically, Microsoft decided that Windows should use a unique disk signature to identify disks, so when Windows first sees a disk it will try to fetch this unique signature and if the value isn't unique it will write a new "unique" value at offset 0x01B8 in the first sector. Note that this behaviour was "retro-actively" included in the UEFI specs in the section relating to (the "protective MBR" part of) the GPT partitioning scheme (where it doesn't apply to unpartitioned disks, MBR partitioned disks or people using BIOS instead of UEFI); and in the UEFI specs it's considered optional (the literal words are "This may be used by the OS...") and there's no clear guidance of which OS (yours or Microsoft's ) gets to decide if the signature is present or not (or how the signature should be generated to allow operating systems to agree on a "unique" value and prevent it from being modified every time a different OS sees the disk). In any case; you want to avoid using the 4 bytes at offset 0x01B8 in your boot sector to defend yourself from Windows.